# Python spawns AWS CLI process for S3 upload and it becomes very slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Python application creates a subprocess for AWS CLI S3 upload.

```
command = 'aws s3 sync /tmp/tmp_dir s3://mybucket/tmp_dir'
# spawn the process
sp = subprocess.Popen(
    shlex.split(str(command)),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# wait for a while
sp.wait()
out, err = sp.communicate()

if sp.returncode == 0:
    logger.info("aws return code: %s", sp.returncode)
    logger.info("aws cli stdout `{}`".format(out))
    return

# handle error
```

`/tmp/tmp_dir` is ~0.5Gb and contains about 100 files.
Upload process takes ~25 minutes, which is extremely slow.

If I run AWS command directly (without Python) it takes less than 1 minute.

What's wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a warning in the documentation about `wait()` usage (see below). However, instead of debugging this, why not rewrite it to use the Python SDK instead of shell out to aws cli? Probably you will get better performance and cleaner code.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html

> Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

edit3:

here is a solution which I just tested and it runs without blocking. There are convenience methods which use wait() or communicate() under the hood, which are easier to use, like check_output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError

command = ['aws','s3','sync','/tmp/test-sync','s3://bucket-name/test-sync']
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(command)
    print(result)
except CalledProcessError as err:
    # handle error, check err.returncode which is nonzero.
    pass
```

Comment: Python SDK does not provide the same functionality right now. I'm using `sync`. It would probably be better, but way more time-consuming. Could you provide an example of a code to avoid pipe block somehow? Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean about sync (recursive copy of dir) not being implemented. Here is a gist I found that might be useful: https://gist.github.com/SavvyGuard/6115006#file-botos3upload-py-L30

Comment: Also I edited my answer to suggest an alternative use of `subprocess`.

Comment: Actually `check_output` is better suited to this task. I posted a new edit.